# Session Management using c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want session management in asp.net application so when ever i am logout my other aspx pages could not open.

Please tell me easy way.

I am new to c# and Asp.net so please ignore my way of asking.

Comment: You should elaborate you question, and show your tried code

Comment: Here's a starting point http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7182/Session-management-options-in-ASP-NET but you need to specify what your question exactly is?

Comment: is that answer helpful to you ?

Comment: @CuongLe I am new to c# and asp.net that is why i cant ask properly but i think some developers have understood my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user logs out.
Do following

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
```

On master page (or all other pages which requires restriction), check

```
If (Session["sessionname"] == null)
{
Respones.Redirect("MyTimeOutPage.aspx");
}
```

-Milind

Comment: Very good answer :) Clear cut instructions that i wanted :) Thanks

Comment: But it should include  Response.Redirect("AdminLoginLMS.aspx"); code after Session.Abandon(); line

Answer (score 2):

IMHO The *easy way* is to work through some tutorials e.g.[Building Secure ASP.NET Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx)

There's no silver bullet here, you have to understand what the underlying framework is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Authentication and Authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization).

This will be easy and help you in your Project.

You can also do by using SessionManagement. If so, Try these links

[ASP.NET Statemanagement Techniques](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/freelance91/ASPNETstatemanagementtechniques01012007212655PM/ASPNETstatemanagementtechniques.aspx) And

[Session Management in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5892/Session-Management-in-ASP-NET)